# Facing CORS error while trying to download a video using youtube-dl-exec in the frontend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api, youtube-dl

```
const url = new Blob(\[selectedLink\]);
const response = await fetch(selectedLink);
const blob = await response.blob();
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = title;
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnbPK.png)

I am working on a project where I use the youtube-dl-exec Node package to obtain a temporary link for a selected video quality. I have successfully retrieved the correct link, but when I attempt to download the video in the frontend, I encounter a CORS error.

The error occurs at the fetch call with the following message:

> Access to fetch at "some temp link" from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I need assistance in resolving this CORS issue and successfully downloading the video using the obtained link in the frontend. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!